# C print longest word

Tags: c

I wrote this program to find and print out the longest word (continuous string of `[a-zA-Z]` characters), where the string is user input. The code works but does have a bug, If I input any special characters like '!' the output will print out the longest word along with some other weird characters. If I do not enter any special characters the program works as intended. I am sure this is something simple, but I haven't been able to figure out what is causing this bug. 
Also any methods of improving the code would be appreciated.

Thank you all for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT 1000

void LongestWord(char sen[]);

int main(void) {
  char input[MAX_INPUT];

  LongestWord(fgets(input, MAX_INPUT, stdin));
  return 0;
}

void LongestWord(char sen[]) {
    int i, current_len, longest_len, input_length;

    input_length = strlen(sen);

    char temp_string[input_length];
    char longest_string[input_length];

    current_len = longest_len = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < input_length; i++) {
        //If it is a letter
        if ((sen[i] >= 97 && sen[i] <= 122) || (sen[i] >= 65 && sen[i] <= 90)) {
            temp_string[current_len] = sen[i];
            current_len++;
        } else {
            if (current_len > longest_len) {
                //Clear longest string
                memset(longest_string, 0, sizeof(longest_string));

                //Copy temp_string to longest string
                strcpy(longest_string, temp_string);

                //set longest length equal to current
                longest_len = current_len;

                //Clear temp_string
                memset(temp_string, 0, sizeof(temp_string));
            }
            current_len = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Longest string: %s\n", longest_string);
}
```

Comment: Use of the function/macro `isalpha` might make the code more readable https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isalpha.htm

Comment: When there are no letters in the string, the `longest_string` is uninitialized. That's where the "weird characters" come from. Move the `memset` before the  loop.

Comment: More generally don't use "magic numbers" such as 92, 122, 65 and 90, when you can use 'a', 'z', 'A', 'Z'.

Comment: The best thing you can do here is to single step through the program with your favourite debugger. You'll learn far more doing that, than having someone on SO point out the problem for you.

Comment: regarding: `char temp_string[input_length];`  This does not allow room for the trailing NUL byte.  Suggest: `char temp_string[ input_length +1 ];`

Comment: OT:  this obscure statement: `if ((sen[i]>=97 && sen[i] <=122) || (sen[i] >=65 && sen[i] <=90 ))`  can be replaced by:  `if( isalpha( sen[i] ) )`

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(longest_string, temp_string);`  The char array: `temp_string[]` has not been NUL terminated, so using `strcpy()` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Longest string: %s\n", longest_string);`  The char array: `longest_string` has not been NUL terminated, so the call to `printf()` results in undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are:

- `temp_string` and longest_string`should be defined with a size of`input_length + 1`
- you should set `longest_string` to an empty string with `*longest_string = '\0';` to avoid printing an uninitialized array if there are no letters on the line.
- avoid hardcoding ASCII values in your code, it is not readable. You could use `(sen[i] >= 'a' && sen[i] <= 'z') || (sen[i] >= 'A' && sen[i] <= 'Z')` or better use `isalpha((unsigned char)sen[i])` from `<ctype.h>`.
- you only test for the longest string if you find a byte that is not a letter. This prevents the last word from being included in the search. You should instead first find a letter, then match all subsequent letters and test if you have found a longer word.
- the calls to `memset` are overkill. You should just set the null terminator in `temp_string` with `temp_string[current_len] = '\0';` so `strcpy` can copy it as a C string and get rid of both `memset` calls.

You don't actually need to copy the substrings, just keep track of the offsets for the current and longest word:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void LongestWord(const char *sen) {
    int i, len, best_start, best_len;

    best_start = best_len = 0;
    for (i = 0; sen[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)sen[i]) {
            // we have a letter: compute the word length
            for (len = 1; isalpha((unsigned char)sen[i + len]; len++)
                continue;
            if (len > best_len) {
                // remember the longest word's offset and length
                best_start = i;
                best_len = len;
            }
            // skip all letters (-1 because of i++ in the for loop)
            i += len - 1;
        }
    }
    // use `%.*s` to print a substring with printf
    printf("Longest string: %.*s\n", best_len, sen + best_start);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point all this out. It makes a lot more sense now.